# Import Resource keyword fails while executing --dryrun command in Robot Framework

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

Impoort Resource keyword fails at --dryrun with error: No keyword found but execution passes.

```
Import Resource    MyResource.robot
MyResource.ABCKeyword    argument
```

In above example, ABCKeyword fails at `--dryrun` but while executing this keyword in a test case passes. I want it to pass this at `--dryrun` also as it's failing in Jenkins build at `--dryrun`.

Let me know what's the alternate to this.

Comment: Does the import thow an error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: At dryrun it shows 'No keyword found', but at execution time, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is behaving as expected. `Import Resource` will not import the resource during a dry run. Since the file isn't imported, the keywords in it won't be known to robot.

I don't think there's an alternate solution, other than to import the resource file in the settings block rather than with the `import resource` keyword.

Comment: I agree with you on this. But in my case, I've python library imported in one of the keywords which I don't want to load. Hence, I'm importing it as a resource in test step only where actually python lib is needed,